# How to throw error if all values of an array has been checked?

Tags: php

I wrote a little function that has an array with a list of values, I'd like to be able to call that function, passing an $amount parameter so it returns a specific amount of information from the array, with the data all being random and unique.

I'm stuck at the error checking part, I'd like to throw an error if we've burned through all the available array list already.

```
function generate_array(int $amount){
    $array = array(0 => array(1), 1 => array(2), 2 => array(3), 3 => array(4));
    $count = 1;
    $arr = array();
    $tested = array();

    while($count <= $amount){
        $value = $array[array_rand($array)][0];

        /**
        * Error checking required
        */
        if(!in_array($value, $tested)) array_push($tested, $value);

        // here I need to check if all the values from $array has already been inserted in $tested or checked each one already
        if(count($tested) === $array) throw new \exception('error');    

        /** End of error checks */

        if(in_array($value, $arr)){
           continue; 
        } else {
            array_push($arr, $value);
            $count++;
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

If we run `print_r(generate_array(4))` we'll get an array with 4 keys, but if we run it with a parameter value of 5 instead of 4, the loop runs endlessly, that's where the error checking problem comes, that I can't think of a way to accomplish it.

I already included what I was trying to do to add error but it doesn't work.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c00657740f7b9e88d0516ad1e5c7ee42807d213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
if(!in_array($value, $tested)) array_push($tested, $value);
```

will only `push` `$value` into `$tested` if it does not exist inside it.

This

```
if(count($tested) === $array) throw new \exception('error');
```

will only `throw` the `Exception` if the number of elements in `$tested` matches `$array`. You are therefore comparing apples and oranges and when all the items are used up and there is at least another element needed to be used, then you will be in that annoying infinite loop. You will therefore need to compare the `count` of elements:

```
if(count($tested) === count($array)) throw new \Exception('error');
```

and you will need to throw this at the start of the loop block. But since you know from the start how many elements you will have in array, you can do a comparison before the loop and `throw` the exception if the criteria is not met:

```
if ($amount > count($array)) throw new Exception('error');
```

and watch the cases in your code, `Exception` is with a big E and this only works for you because you are using Windows. If you run this code on a case-sensitive environment, the code will crash.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just adding before the loop an error check?

```
if (count($array) < $amount) {
    return false;
}

while ($count <= $amount) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a million things you could do, but if you're looking to do it in the while() loop, just add this at the end:

```
if($count == $amount)
{
throw new \exception('error'); //If you want an error thrown
break; //If you want to exit the loop after the "last go"
}
```

Or if you want to do the error check at the beginning of the loop, then change the condition to something like:

```
if($amount > $count)
{
throw new \exception('error'); //If you want an error thrown
break; //If you want to exit the loop
}
```

Comment: You just burned me alive, if there's a "million things I could do", yet couldn't even figure out 1, I should quit life lol

Comment: Sorry, I fail at being nice to people, I should quit life too. :(

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even use a loop to begin with? You could just check if the callee is requesting more data than is available (`$amount > count($array)`) to throw your error and then just `shuffle()` the array once and return the slice from `0` to `$amount - 1` from the array. That way you only shuffle the data array once and there won't be any endless loops.

Answer (score 0):

Depending if the array your generating from can be changed slightly, you could simplify the whole code...

```
function generate_array(int $amount){
    $array = array(0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 4);
    shuffle($array);
    return ($amount <= count($array))?array_slice($array, 0, $amount):false;
}
```

This uses `shuffle()` to mix the array up and then `array_slice()` to take the required number of elements.

It uses `$amount <= count($array)` to check the number of items, but you could miss this out as `array_slice()` would just return up to the number of items in the source array